# Determinant problem $n\times n$ with $0$'s and $1$'s

Tags: matrices, determinant

$$D_n=\left\vert\begin{matrix}0&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right\vert$$

Can anyone help me with this determinant? I tried to use Laplace and after that recursive formula but that didn't help.

Comment: I think write it as addition of $2$ determinants

Comment: You can use the recursive definition of the determinant to get a recurrence relation between $D_n$ and $D_{n-2}$

Answer (score 3):

If you calculate $D_n$ using Laplace's expansion along the first row twice, you get

$$D_n = (-1) \cdot \left\vert\begin{matrix}
1&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right\vert = (-1) \cdot \left( 1 \cdot \left\vert\begin{matrix}
0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
0&0&\cdots&1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right\vert \\ + (-1) \cdot 
\left\vert\begin{matrix}
0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots& \\
0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
0&0&\cdots&1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right\vert \right) = -D_{n-2} $$

Thus, starting from $D_1 = 0$ and $D_2 = (-1)$ we get

$$ D_{2n} = (-1)^n, \,\,\, D_{2n+1} = 0. $$

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the typo.